# AWS VPC - Edit DNS Hostnames issue with public IP ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have encountered a strange issue with getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I don't have DNS hostnames enabled in my custom VPC.

I have created a VPC with one subnet (public), one route table, and an Internet gateway.

My route table has a route to my Internet gateway. I am using the default Network ACL. My SG has ports 1024-65535 open (<--- this is just a test!).

I create an instance from the AWS Linux AMI and put it in my public subnet. When my VPC is configured to assign DNS hostnames via enabling in "Edit DNS Hostnames", then I can reach my instance from my browser. (Instance is a Nodejs web service). All works fine, and network interface flow logs verify traffic is reaching my instance.

I disable the DNS hostname creation in my VPC via "Edit DNS Hostnames". I create a new instance following the same steps. It does not have DNS hostnames as expected (private nor public), but it does have a public IP address. When I try to connect to my instance via public IP via browser, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

It appears that I can readily reproduce this error with success/failure via enable/disable DNS hostnames.

Am I missing something in my configuration? Is this a known issue? Am I smoking crack?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not enable DNS hostnames in a VPC?  I can't think of a reason to do that.  But check the node process startup.  It's probably failing to find it's own hostname, thus failing to start, or whatever's in front of it (Nginx, etc., if anything) is failing to start.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason not to enable DNS hostnames either, but that was the default setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was Nodejs web service is failing to find the hostname for binding...because I was pulling the hostname to bind from the meta-data in the #!/bin/bash UserData script:

```
# Grab the EC2 instance internal DNS and configure the Hapi server host value
localhost=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)
rm -f ServerHost.js
echo -n "module.exports = \"" > ServerHost.js
echo -n "$localhost" >> ServerHost.js
echo "\"" >> ServerHost.js
```

But since there is no private DNS (because the default when manually creating a VPC is 'disable'), then there is no 'local-hostname'.